# Reset css makes @import of Google font face not work

Tags: css, import, font-family

I have [Meyers Reset Css](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/meyer-reset/) one-line of rules just above my other CSS, but the `Hind` font is not applying, and instead it's using Times New Roman it appears.

If you comment out the Reset Css line, the Hind font applies.

Why is the Reset Css making my Hind font-family not apply? Even if I put `font-family:'Hind'` inside both `html { }` and `body { }`, it still only applies if Reset Css isn't present.

My Css:

```
// Reset Css bunch of rules here
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind:400,600,700);
html { background: #F5F5F5; font-family: "Hind"; }
```

Live demo: http://jsbin.com/yudeziqiki/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: In the demo you have written `@@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind:400,600,700);` with two `@`. Is it normal ?

Comment: Updated. My bad. Live demo here: http://jsbin.com/yudeziqiki/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to place the `@import` before the reset.

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind:400,600,700);
/* Meyers Reset Css Here */
```

Answer (score 1):

> The @import CSS at-rule is used to import style rules from other style sheets. These rules must precede all other types of rules, [...]
>   [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import)

Just put the `@import` rule before the reset CSS, and your problem is solved.